# @readfile in php?

Tags: php, readfile

I hate that google can not search for symbols. I saw this in some sample code and wondered why there is an @ sign before the readfile function:

```
@readfile($filename);
```

What does it mean different to without an @ symbol?

Comment: Also, as a heads up for next time whenever you come across a symbol, try spelling it out instead, i.e 'at sign' you might be able to find more results.

Comment: Also, PHP has a pretty good online help. For the most part you can simply do `http://php.net/[something]` and get to the right page. And yes, in this case, the `[something]` can actually be `@`: http://php.net/@

Comment: use this while googling "@readfile()"

Comment: would you consider renaming the issue to something like "what does the @ symbol mean before a PHP function?"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An `@` before a command in PHP means that no errors are printed. It's called the [error control operator](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

If you removed the `@` and `readfile` would encounter an error (such as not being able to read the file), then—depending on your PHP settings—the error message will be amidst your site content; something you rarely, if ever, want. (It gets worse even, if this happens before a call to `header()` or `start_session()` because once content is sent, the headers can't be written anymore.)

Answer (score 10):

I refer to @ as being the "stfu operator".

Answer (score 6):

**[It is PHP's error suppression operator.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)** With it you can suppress error messages.

**Tip:**

Simply don’t use the error suppression operator with speed-critical code.

**Future:**

Because `@` operator is very slow, it won't work on `ini_set` eg `@ini_set` in future version of PHP eg PHP6

**Important Reading:**

**[Bad uses of the @ operator](http://michelf.com/weblog/2005/bad-uses-of-the-at-operator/)**

Answer (score 5):

It's [error control operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). Manual will tell you everything...

Answer (score 3):

@ means "don't show errors/warnings"

Answer (score 0):

**FYI**

You can use " " to search queries containing special characters in google.

Example to search - **@readfile in PHP?** [search it](https://www.google.com/search?ei=_AstX6yOF5L8rQGLw4-wDA&q=%40readfile+in+PHP%3F&oq=%40readfile+in+PHP%3F&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgQIABAeOggIABAFEAoQHjoGCAAQCBAeOgYIABAHEB46CAgAEAcQChAeUL_IBFik0wRgu98EaAJwAHgAgAG6AYgB0QSSAQMyLjOYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwis_I7h0YjrAhUSfisKHYvhA8YQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)

You can search    - **"@readfile in PHP?"** [search it](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%40readfile+in+PHP%3F%22&filter=0&biw=1920&bih=949)